# Joining table without a common field

Tags: sql-server, null, left-join

I am trying to populate table A.OMkt based on table B.Def.

My initial thought is to do it using a LEFT JOIN ON A.OMkt = B.Zip.

But the ones highlighted in 'yellow' always comes back as a null as I don't have an equivalent in table B. I'd appreciate any help. I'd like to avoid creating another column and would like to complete the join with just the columns already present.

[image]

Comment: They becomes as NULL because you're using a LEFT JOIN and the values doesn't match on the keys. Please next time **do not** post data as images, instead post them as _formatted text_. Thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind the desired results?   I assume this is sample data and not real data.  So suggesting anything based on the example might not solve your actual problem.

Comment: Hi 
This is my first time using the website to post a question. So please bear with me.

Comment: @TabAlleman 

I am trying to populate column OMkt based on the match between A.O3Zip and B.Zip.

Essentially, for 605 it is going to pull in A but for A2J I get a null value as A2J not equal to A2, only the first two characters match.

Comment: I get that, but what is the logic that you want to match on with your real data?   Is it that you want to match only on the first two characters?  You need to have a logical rule that you want to match on for ALL rows.

Comment: Yup, that is correct. So this where I am getting an error. I have two codes to this.
code 1:
Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B  ON A.O3Zip = B.Zip

code2:
Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B  ON A.O3Zip like B.Zip + '%'

Both give me a NULL value where there is no match (i.e in case of A2, B2, V0).

Comment: I wish I could show the actual data on SQL but there are way too many columns to fit in one so just tried to provide a sample dataset.

Comment: What do you want the fields in yellow to be?  OR do you want the 3 rows with yellow fields to be excluded from the results?

Comment: "populate table based on" means nothing. This is like saying, "I want a result". This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. PS Make a minimal example with representative data. Explain re being stuck. Clarify via edits not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a simple `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ta.O3Zip, COALESCE(ta.OMkt, tb.Def) OMKt
FROM tableA ta
LEFT JOIN tableB tb ON ta.O3Zip = tb.zip
```

This query will look up values in `tableB`, matching column `tableA.O3Zip` with column `tableB.zip`. When `OMkt` is `NULL`, then it will be replaced by the value of `Def` in `tableB` (if available).

Comment: Hi
I think I might have misrepresented. 
Column OMkt is the column I need to populate

Comment: I am trying to populate column OMkt based on the match between A.O3Zip and B.Zip. Essentially, for 605 it is going to pull in A but for A2J I get a null value as A2J not equal to A2, only the first two characters match

Comment: @KruthikaKumaraguru: what would you like to do in this case, match only on the first two characters? If yes, how do you want to handle the case where more than one record in `tableB` has the same first two characters in `zip` as in `tableA.O3Zip`?

Comment: For the ones where the match happens with 3 characters, well and good. But if it doesn't then I need to match with 2 characters.

Comment: There are two codes I was trying to work with 

Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B  ON A.O3Zip = B.Zip


Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B  ON A.O3Zip like B.Zip + '%'

Answer (score 0):

> Table A LEFT JOIN Table B ON A.O3Zip like B.Zip + '%' Both give me a
>   NULL value where there is no match (i.e in case of A2, B2, V0)

If you are getting a NULL with this LIKE in the JOIN condition, then it must be because you have whitespace characters in the `B.Zip` column.

Try like this:

```
Table A LEFT JOIN Table B ON A.O3Zip LIKE RTRIM(B.Zip) + '%'
```